# Why do non dispatchable handles use a ptr on 64bit platofrms?

Tags: c, vulkan

Why are non dispatchable handles not always a `uint64_t`? Why is it neccessary that they are represented as a `ptr` on 64bit platforms?

```
#if !defined(VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE)
#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_WIN64) || (defined(__x86_64__) && !defined(__ILP32__) ) || defined(_M_X64) || defined(__ia64) || defined (_M_IA64) || defined(__aarch64__) || defined(__powerpc64__)
        #define VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE(object) typedef struct object##_T *object;
#else
        #define VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE(object) typedef uint64_t object;
#endif
#endif
```

The spec says

> Non-dispatchable handle types are a 64-bit integer type whose meaning is implementation-dependent, and may encode object information directly in the handle rather than acting as a reference to an underlying object. Objects of a non-dispatchable type may not have unique handle values within a type or across types. If handle values are not unique, then destroying one such handle must not cause identical handles of other types to become invalid, and must not cause identical handles of the same type to become invalid if that handle value has been created more times than it has been destroyed.

Comment: I think that their idea was to make it sure for C & C++ are 64 bits and to not realy of the built in typed. But their idea is IMO quite weird

Comment: The hack with the struct and the ## token pasting operator makes handles type safe.  You get different struct types with different handle types, mixing them up in code now produces a compile error.  This was probably discovered to be useful long after they committed to a plain integer type in earlier 32-bit only releases, hard to make such a change since it can produce build errors on buggy code that somehow chugged along anyway.  I would guess that somebody was inspired by the way handles are declared another widely used api.

Comment: It is just a cludge. Under the hood they are usually pointers. I guess they are 64 bit to support 64 bit platforms. It is probably desirable they are the same size on 32 bit platforms. So 64 bits, even if only 32 are used. Therefore they cannot be defined as pointers on the 32 bit platform. Using 64 bit integers on a 64 bit platform when they are actually 64 bit pointers may have some subtle disadvantage. The whole point of "handles" is encapsulation so, in theory, you do not care what the type is.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw I doubt they use pointers under the hood. If at the bottom they allocate from an array,then the pointers may become invalidated once the array is resized. Those probably indices converted to pointer values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't necessary that they use pointers, only that they are 64 bit.

The reason pointers are used when possible is because C and C++ don't have strong typedefs so using pointers give a little bit of extra type safety because you cannot assign a `VkImageView_T*` to a `VkImage_T*`.